# Applicatoin.SumProduct/Countifs in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the Application SumProduct & Countifs in vba rather than the .Formula method. Below is an example of the report I run every month:

[image]

I need to be able to organize this data by multiple criteria.  Below is a picture of the spreadsheet where I'm attempting to organize this data by the given criteria:

[image]

I've created macros so the user of this spreadsheet enters the criteria on one tab, and then this tab is automatically formatted based on their input.  The data needs to be organized as follows:

Adjuster Home Office Name>Data Set (Column C from the report)>Claim Type (Column E from the report)>State (Column G from the report)

after making several attempts at this, I know that the countifs within sumproduct formula will achieve this.  Below is a snippet of the code I've written so far:

```
Dim linerngs As Range
Dim lineitem As Range
Dim lastlinerow As Long
Dim Tab1LastRow As Long
Dim claimstab As String

Dim wsf
Dim SpecialStates As Range
Dim DedicatedUnits As Range
Dim HomeOffice As String
Dim DataSet As String

claimstab = Sheet2.Range("C2") & " Claims"
priorclaimstab = Sheet2.Range("C3") & " Claims"

Tab1LastRow = Sheets(claimstab).Cells(Sheets(claimstab).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Set SpecialStates = Sheet2.Range("E2:AA2")
Set DedicatedUnits = Sheet2.Range("E5:BB5")

lastlinerow = Sheet2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set linerngs = Sheet2.Range("D12:D" & lastlinerow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

    For Each lineitem In linerngs

HomeOffice = lineitem.Offset(0, -3).Value
DataSet = lineitem.Offset(0, -1).Value

firsttype = lineitem.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False)
lasttype = lineitem.Offset(0, 6).Address(False, False)

firststate = lineitem.Offset(0, 7).Address(False, False)
laststate = lineitem.Offset(0, 15).Address(False, False)

ClaimTypes = Sheet2.Range(firsttype & ":" & lasttype)
StateJuris = Sheet2.Range(firststate & ":" & laststate)

    If InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "Indemnity") > 0 And InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "AOS") = 0 Then

        lineitem.Offset(0, 16) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & Tab1LastRow), HomeOffice, Sheets(claimstab).Range("C2:C" & Tab1LastRow), DataSet, Sheets(claimstab).Range("E2:E" & Tab1LastRow), ClaimTypes, Sheets(claimstab).Range("G2:G" & Tab1LastRow), StateJuris))

    End If

Next lineitem
```

This is returning me a value of zero for everything.  I started poking around and found that if I replace the variable "ClaimTypes" with "IN" and replace the variable "StateJuris" with "TX" or any other state abbreviation within the Countifs code, it gives me a correct calculation.  I know in the spreadsheet formula version of countifs, you can reference a horizontal line of cells and evaluate them at once.  For instance, if you look at row 12 of the second image, i'd need to be able to evaluate Column G of the report in the first image for the states "AK";"CA";"HI";"TX" .

I cant figure out how to make this work with the VBA Application version of countifs & sumproduct.  any help on this would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

In order to not count what states are in range E5:W5 in the second image i posted, i tried something like this:

```
        If InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "Indemnity") > 0 And InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "AOS") > 0 Then
        c = 0
        For Each ClaimType In ClaimTypes
            For Each DedState In DedicatedUnits
            c = c + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & Tab1LastRow), HomeOffice, Sheets(claimstab).Range("C2:C" & Tab1LastRow), DataSet, Sheets(claimstab).Range("E2:E" & Tab1LastRow), ClaimType.Value, Sheets(claimstab).Range("G2:G" & Tab1LastRow), "<>" & DedState.Value))
            Next DedState
        Next ClaimType

        lineitem.Offset(0, 16) = c
        End If
```

however, this isn't working and i didn't think that i would.  I'm assuming i need to do something like:

```
If InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "Indemnity") > 0 And InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "AOS") > 0 Then

    c = 0
    nc = 0

For Each ClaimType In ClaimTypes

c = c + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & Tab1LastRow), HomeOffice, Sheets(claimstab).Range("C2:C" & Tab1LastRow), DataSet, Sheets(claimstab).Range("E2:E" & Tab1LastRow), ClaimType.Value))

Next ClaimType


For Each ClaimType In ClaimTypes

    For Each DedState In DedicatedUnits

            nc = nc + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & Tab1LastRow), HomeOffice, Sheets(claimstab).Range("C2:C" & Tab1LastRow), DataSet, Sheets(claimstab).Range("E2:E" & Tab1LastRow), ClaimType.Value, Sheets(claimstab).Range("G2:G" & Tab1LastRow), DedState.Value))

    Next DedState

Next ClaimType

    lineitem.Offset(0, 16) = c - nc

End If
```

Comment: isn't there only one argument to SUMPRODUCT here?

Comment: I apologize, i guess i wasn't clear enough.  im using countifs within a sumproduct formula to calculate based on all of the different criteria.

Comment: sorry, that makes no sense to me.  COUNTIFS returns a scalar.  SUMPRODUCT on a scalar returns the scalar.  The SUMPRODUCT isn't doing anything here...  What exactly do you want to return?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: assume that in the second image, Cell F12 contained the text "EL".  the only way in the past that ive been able to capture multiple claim types & multiple states of jurisdiction in one formula was to use a COUNTIFS within a SUMPRODUCT and also use a CHOOSE function thrown in as well.  If you know of a better way PLEASE let me know.

Comment: sorry its hard to explain what I'm trying to do without going into a large level of detail in the industry I'm working in.

Comment: @GrahamChandler Based on your comment to the answer below, it seems you are in the habit of relying on Excel Functions within your VBA applications - don't do this. You are severely limiting the power available to you through VBA, and you are painting yourself into corners that wouldn't exist if you had a wider toolset available.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon i could not agree more.  I just haven't found a better way to do what i need to do without them.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'd love to do this a different way because this takes sooooooo long to calculate

Comment: Like Batman in The Dark Knight Rises, you won't be able to fully commit to learning non-Excel-Function tools unless you take them away from yourself. For every Excel Function tool you have, there's probably a better VBA option available [every once in a while a shortcut through Excel Functions is handy, but you won't even know when it's worth it and when it isn't, if you're always relying on them].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can just use `SUM()` here instead of `SUMPRODUCT()` - you are only supplying one argument to `SUMPRODUCT()`, so it is only returning the sum anyway.

Secondly, if you really wanted to do an array formula in VBA, wrap the entire formula in `EVALUATE([formula])`.  But this won't work for you because...

Thirdly, even if you entered this as an array formula in an excel worksheet, it would not work correctly if there was multiple criteria for both `claim types` and `states`, as it would only add the number of occurrences of `claim1` and `state1` and `claim2` and `state2` etc.  (If either column only has one, then the formula would work, however.)

So, if you want to do this, what I would do is a nested `FOR` loop, where for each `Claim Type-State` combination, you do another `COUNTIFS()` using that particular `Claim Type` and `State` and increment a running total.

Update: For example, something like

```
c = 0
for each claimType in claimTypes
    for each state in StateJuris
        c = c + wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & Tab1LastRow), HomeOffice, Sheets(claimstab).Range("C2:C" & Tab1LastRow), DataSet, Sheets(claimstab).Range("E2:E" & Tab1LastRow), ClaimType.value, Sheets(claimstab).Range("G2:G" & Tab1LastRow), State.value)
    next state
next claimType

lineitem.Offset(0, 16) = c
```

Comment: In my opinion, Array Formulas in Excel are quite clunky and should only be used within Excel sheets; within VBA other options are generally better - and you've pointed out a lot of reasons why in this case.

Comment: @dashnick these are the exact problems ive ran into in the past.  I've used the Choose function within the Countifs for the claim type criteria in the past and that worked.  and then for the next criteria (states), i would just reference a range that contained each state i needed to count for each claim type.

Comment: Agree with @Grade'Eh'Bacon here - array formulas are fun for excel worksheets, but if you are in code anyway, just use for loops.

Comment: this is the spreadsheet formula ive used in the past:

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$25&" Claims'!B:B"),"<> ",INDIRECT("'"&$B$25&" Claims'!C:C"),G2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$25&" Claims'!E:E"),CHOOSE({1;2},I2,J2),INDIRECT("'"&$B$25&" Claims'!G:G"),O2:W2))

the choose function allowed me to count multiple criterias for claim types and states.

assume that I2:J2 is the range for my ClaimTypes variable and O2:W2 is the range for my StateJuris variable.

Comment: yes that would work, but it is obviously very clunky, and inherently is doing its own nested `for` loops anyway.  Again, no need for such things in VBA, just use loops.

Comment: @dashnick would you mind providing some basic syntax for how this would work?  if you just provide the basic idea i can probably handle the rest.

Comment: one last question @dashnick  ... if you look a the second image in my initial post, youll see the range E5:W5 contains state abbreviations.  These are states i do not need to count claims for.  to achieve this, will i need to make a calculation for what i need to count, and a separate calculation for what i don't need to count and take the difference of the two?  I'm finding that using a "<>" operator isn't working

Comment: you are probably doing something like if `If Range("e5")<> state then` - the problem here would be those are actually range references, so they will never be equal since they don't refer to the same cell.  (in this case you could do `Range("e5").value <> state.value` or something).  But actually you should do another `countif` to see if state is in e5:w5, and only do the increment if not.

Comment: @dashnick i'll edit my post to show what i attempted to do